# Connection of serial pin on ATMEGA328P to connector B type(female) D+ and D-

Tags: serial, atmega328

Now I am using ATMEGA328P and want to communicate with computer in serial using B connector female (also want to provide power from computer to ATMEGA328P using B connector).

So here is my question. How can I connect D+ and D- to ATMEGA328P's pin No. 2 (PD0/RX) and pin No. 3 (PD1/TX)? In other words which pin should I connect to D+ and D- ? Also is it possible to connect them directly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you examined the schematic of an Arduino device that uses the '328P?

Comment: I have seen the schematic of Arduino but  they connect D- and D+ to ATMEGA1602. But this time I want to use ATMEGA328P only.

Comment: Did you ever stop to wonder why they do that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, maybe due to converting. But now I am asking is it possible doing that with ATMEGA328P only?

Comment: Pull up the datasheets for both devices; you don't need the complete datasheets, just the summary datasheets will do. Examine and compare the front pages.

Comment: I did. But really don't get what to see. If possible could please explain weather it is possible to use ATMEGA328P only.

Comment: Are you asking how to connect a USB "B" connector to pins 2 and 3 of the Atmega328P?

Comment: Yes. Exactly.  I want to realize serial communication with computer.

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino Uno (and similar boards) have a chip on them that does serial communication via a dedicated USB chip (the ATmega16U2 chip). You can't just connect pins 2 and 3 to D+ and D- and turn that into USB.

You can conceivably do it using [V-USB](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html) which does USB in software in conjunction with a few extra components.

You can also buy external serial to USB adapters which do the conversion externally. If you Google `serial to usb adapter` you will find quite a few for around $3.

Comment: The Adafruit Trinket Pro https://www.adafruit.com/product/2000 uses this, so does the usbasp (not Arduino code) http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/ @zalt, if you have to ask, don't do this. I has special requirements for the hardware and software, and it is something for advanced engineers. Stay away from it.

Comment: ok I did with HID-class USB Serial Communication for AVRs using V-USB. I  could monitor the incoming data to PC  by HID Serial Monitor.
However, I need to monitor the incoming data by Serial monitor such as tera-term or Arduino's serial monitor.
Is there anyway to do that with HID-class ?
I tried trinket-fake-usb-serial, but did not work at all.
Please I need help.

Comment: This sounds like a different question to me. First you ask if certain ports can be connected to a USB device, now you are asking about monitoring serial data with a HID-class USB. I suggest you make a new question. Offhand, using a HID (Human Interface Device) when there isn't a human there clicking away seems like a misuse of the hardware.

Comment: All I want to do is just getting the serial data from MCU(ATMEGAA328P) 
 to PC  without using serial to usb adapter.

Comment: The Atmega328P doesn't have a USB interface so what you want isn't really practical. There is no "simple wiring" that will achieve that.